# Vue Js | Data not getting reflected on html

Tags: vue.js, webpack, import, webpack-4

I am very new to Vue js, for practise I created a simple html and a js for Vue but I do not see my data binding to the html, I do not even get unresolved variable reflected {{message}}, Instead a function is returned in place of my dom.

Following is my snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>First Vue App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
      {{message}}
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Script:
main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';

var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        message:"First Vue app"
    }
});
```

I am using webpack bundle. My dist has the above index.html and main.js.

Please note that I do not get any error in the console also I tried using v-cloak as suggested in one of the solutions.

Following is my console image:
[image]